# How can I send a "UIControlEventValueChanged" event from my custom control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontrolevents, target-action

I've created a custom picker view type of control by subclassing UIView. I would like to be able to send a "UIControlEventValueChanged" control event from within this control, so that I can register for it in whichever view controller is using the control.

How can I can I get my custom control to trigger this event when I deem it should be triggered?

Comment: Protocols or via NSNotificationCenter is the way to go. Would personally choose protocols in this case. Have a look at http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: These days it is simply `sendActions(for: .blah)` eg for `.valueChanged`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Assuming your custom control extends `UIControl`, then you simply do:

```
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

This will call all registered targets (via `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` that this event has happened.

Use this function where you deem should trigger a value has changed

Comment: All my controls extend UIView since UIControl extends UIView do you think I could simply switch all my control to subclass UIControl without having to change anything else?

Comment: Custom controls should always extend `UIControl`. This gives you all of the benefits of that class. Once you change your class to extend `UIControl`, the only thing you may have to do is strip out code you now get for free from `UIControl` that you weren't getting from `UIView`.