# iOS Swift: Send action (control event) from subclass of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, action, uitapgesturerecognizer

How can I send action (similar kind of tap event) from sub class of UIImageView to View Controller.

[Here is reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17385647/5638630), that I want to apply for UIImageView. (UIImageView does not have UIControl in its super class hierarchy)

Following is my code but not working as I don't know, how to implement, what I need.

```
class TappableImageView: UIImageView {
  // Initializer methods.....

   //------------------------------------------
    private func addTapGesture(){
        let tapOnImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TappableImageView.handleTapGesture(tapGesture:)))
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnImage)

    }


    //----------------------------------------------
    @objc func handleTapGesture(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // how can I send tap/click event to all view controllers, where I've used this image  from this point. 
    }
}
```

Is there any alternate/other solution that may work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you to use a closure to handle taps:

```swift
class TappableImageView: UIImageView {

   var handleTap: (() -> Void)? = nil


   //------------------------------------------
    private func addTapGesture(){
        let tapOnImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TappableImageView.handleTapGesture(tapGesture:)))
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnImage)

    }


    //----------------------------------------------
    @objc func handleTapGesture(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        handleTap?()
    }
}
```

And then I your view controller you can use this i.e. in `viewDidLoad` method:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourTappableImageView.handleTap = { 
       print("an image view was tapped")
    }
}
```

It assumes that your `TappableImageView` is stored in variable named `yourTappableImageView`.

Comment: this part:
`yourTappableImageView.handleTap = { print("an image view was tapped") }`
is crucial. Could you show the code of your's view controller? Maybe you are missing something